# efficiency of algorithm - are all string elements unique

Tags: python-3.x, performance, time-complexity

The task: Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters.

I wrote two functions that dose that. How do I start to asses which one is better/more efficient?
what are the things to look for?

this is the first one:

```
def is_unique(word):
    start = 0
    len_word = len(word)

    while start < len_word:
        for i in range(start + 1, len_word):
            if word[start] == word[i]:
                return False
        start += 1
    return True
```

second one:

```
def unique_list(word):
    unique = []

    for i in word:
        if i in unique:
            return False
        else:
            unique += i
     return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both algorithms are inefficient: their complexity is `O(n^2)` with `n` the number of character in `word`.
The second algorithm will be a bit faster in practice because it uses the build-in Python operation `i in unique` (rather than slow CPython loops).

The test can be done in a much faster way: `len(set(s)) == len(s)`.
This line tests if the string contains unique characters in `O(n)` (since the string characters can be converted to a set in linear time).

Comment: Your solution is so elegant! And the performance must be quite optimal in the general case since all the work is done in the `set` constructor, implemented in executable code. Yet for long strings with duplicate characters coming early in the string, both approaches by the OP will return false quicker. Constructing the set incrementally might be more appropriate if duplicates are more likely to occur than not.